# Writing a custom task via UsingTask in .NET Core keeps failing to build (missing assemblies)

Tags: .net-core

My goal is to run tasks in .NET Core (akin to `rake` in Rails land), so I can execute code outside the normal control flow of the application's lifecycle.  I have seen there are projects like [albacore](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore) that supposedly accomplish this, but I'm trying to do it "the .NET way", rather than bringing in a separate ruby dependency to accomplish this.

After following [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) on *Task Writing* for `msbuild`, I have managed to create a simple `Task` that implements the `ITask` interface as suggested in the article:

**EcommerceSite/Tasks/ScrapeAll.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;  
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace Tasks
{
    public class ScrapeAll : Task
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My `.csproj` file uses the `UsingTask` element to register my task code, and I have a `Target` that invokes the task:

**EcommerceSite/EcommerceSite.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup> 

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="15.3.409" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="15.3.409" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Views\ItemPage\" />
    <Folder Include="Tasks\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="Tasks.ScrapeAll" AssemblyFile="bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/EcommerceSite.dll" />

  <Target Name="ScrapeAll">
    <Tasks.ScrapeAll />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

So now, on my command line, I am able to invoke: `dotnet msbuild /t:ScrapeAll` and yet, I get this error:

```
error MSB4062: The "Tasks.ScrapeAll" task could not be loaded from the assembly 
[redacted]/EcommerceSite/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/EcommerceSite.dll. 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.

[redacted]/EcommerceSite/EcommerceSite.csproj(33,5): error MSB4062:  
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, 
and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is my `Task` trying to load `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures`, which according to the [NuGet docs](http://view%20rendering%20features%20such%20as%20view%20engines,%20views,%20view%20components,%20and%20HTML%20helpers), contains:

   > view rendering features such as view engines, views, view components, and HTML helpers

of which my `Task` does nothing of the sort?

2. How do I make it try to load this assembly, or if that is not an option, how do I resolve the dependency issue?

Comment: Having pretty much the exact same problem. When I build via "dotnet msbuild" I get pretty much the same error: [...] error MSB4036: The "PublishValidationTask" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201" directory.

Answer (score 3):

I got this working tonight. You can see [my solution here](https://github.com/cleemullins/CustomBuildTargets/tree/master/PublishPipelineTesting).

In essence, I hit 2 problems:

1. I was including the namespace in the  element. Once I remove that and just used the class name, the error went away.

> ```
> <UsingTask TaskName="PublishValidationTask"
> AssemblyFile="C:\git\CustomBuildTargets\PublishPipelineTesting\bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0\PublishPipelineTesting.dll"
> />
> ```

2. Only when I set **Importance="High"** would text show up on the command line.

> ```
> C:\git\CustomBuildTargets\PublishPipelineTesting>dotnet msbuild PublishPipelineTesting.csproj
> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Core
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>   PublishPipelineTesting -> C:\git\CustomBuildTargets\PublishPipelineTesting\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\PublishPipelineTesting.dll
>   This is a test
>   Hello World
> ```

3. Paths also made things weird. I started with an absolute path, which worked well. From there I was able to figure out the relative path, which was simply starting in the **bin** directory:

> AssemblyFile="bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0\PublishPipelineTesting.dll" />

Once I got that working, and the custom task running, return true/false would allow the build to pass or fail, which is exactly what I wanted. When returning "false", I would now get:

> C:\git\CustomBuildTargets\PublishPipelineTesting>dotnet run
>   PublishPipelineTesting.csproj
>
> The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

When return true out of the task, the build would pass and the project would run:

> C:\git\CustomBuildTargets\PublishPipelineTesting>dotnet run
>   PublishPipelineTesting.csproj
>   Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I was having was that the project that was containing my tasks was targeting the netcoreapp2.1 framework .... I changed it to target netstandard2.0 as well, then went into the  target and changed the assembly file path to be the netstandard2.0 instead of netcoreapp2.1. After that, the custom task I have worked perfectly.